# Debugging Ionic 4 App in Appium WebdriverIO not working : WebView missing

Tags: ionic-framework, webview, appium, browserstack

I am trying to debug an Ionic 4 app using Appium & WebdriverIO. I am receiving feedback that I need to enable Webview in my app in order for this to work. The problem is I cannot find a single reference as to how to do this in Ionic anywhere.

I have also attempted to run my app in Browserstack where for the same reason, it won't run at all.

Can someone from Ionic comment on the correct approach to this, that will work for Android and iOS platforms, based on the same Ionic code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution comes in a few steps.

### 1 - Enable Webview

In the config.xml file, make sure you set the following:

```
 <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
```

This has the effect of setting :

```
 <application
    android:debuggable="true"
```

### 2 - Debug Build

In addition to point 1, note that for a production release build, we use the command :

$ ionic cordova build android --prod --release

However, Android does something clever behind the scenes in that this build can only be debugged locally for security reasons. So, no matter what you do, when you try and run this up in Browserstack, it will not provide webview as a context. We fix this by using the debug build flag:

$ ionic cordova build android --prod --debug

### 3 - Bonus Bug

Unfortunately, there is a bug in the Android Debug build process. So there is one more step to cover. You have to run zipalign twice when you're working on the debug build. Don't ask me why! You just do...

```
Debug > "%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\28.0.3\zipalign" -f 4 app-debug.apk temp.apk    // zip-align
Debug > "%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\28.0.3\zipalign" -f 4 temp.apk SensorNode.apk   // need to do it twice because of android bug!!!
Debug > "%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\28.0.3\apksigner" sign --ks my-release-key.jks --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true SensorNode.apk
```